# Laravel: Disable Artisan console output when running tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

When running PHPUnit tests that are testing an `Artisan` command PHPUnit outputs any console `->info() or ->writeln()` function calls.

Tests to not fail due to this although its ugly.

Example:

[image]

see the progress bar? How can we disable output during testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options come in mind all operate with *verbosity* of the command:

- use `--quiet|-q` flag within `call()`
- use `callSilent()` instead of `call()` (from test itself)
- resolve command out of container and set verbosity to `quiet` before using it: `$cmd = resolve(Command::class); $cmd->setVerbosity('quiet'); $cmd->doWork();`
- make dummy command that extends your tested one and set verbosity to quiet `$this->setVerbosity('quiet');` and obviously resolve/new up the dummy command instead

Example of the latest (yes in one file):

```
class TestCommand extends TestCase {

    ...

}

class DummyCommand extends RealCommand {

    function __constructor() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setVerbosity('quiet');
    }

}
```

Comment: What if the output is from an external dependancy of the command? and not the Command itself.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan if you don't need the output at all, just surround your `call()` with
`ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`